# deepcopy time doubling on subsequent copies of different instances of same class

Tags: python, performance, copy

When running `deepcopy` from the Python `copy` module on instances of a class, the copy process time doubles with each iteration, even though the instances are all of the same class and (at least in my mind) should therefor take an identical amount of time to copy.

The object I'm copying uses `kwargs` to set a bunch of attributes. It also originally called a `set_dynamic_attributes` method in `__init__` to configure some of the attributes according to some logic, but in order to test if that was causing the slowdown, I removed the call from the `__init__` and called it specifically.

Here's the offending section, and the results of it:

```py
for a in base_wpn.base_attacks:
    t0 = time.time()
    a.set_dynamic_attributes()
    t1 = time.time()
    print('Dyn attributes set time: ' + str(t1-t0))
    atk = deepcopy(a)
    t2 = time.time()
    print('Deepcopy time: ' + str(t2-t1))
```

Result:

```
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.01399993896484375
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.03599882125854492
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.04999995231628418
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.09999823570251465
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.011002540588378906
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.021996021270751953
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.0429990291595459
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.08499836921691895
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.17699956893920898
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.32700061798095703
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 0.6589939594268799
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 1.4200007915496826
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 2.466003656387329
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 5.228000164031982
Dyn attributes set time: 0.0
Deepcopy time: 10.528998374938965
```

In case it helps (I know it's not reproable without a ton more code, lots of object references), here's the object definition that the instances are built from:

```py
class Attack():
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.skill = [self.weapon.skill]
        self.attack_mod = self.weapon.attack_mod
        self.parry_mod = -self.weapon.parry_mod #Modifier to OPPONENT'S parry chance
        self.stamina = self.weapon.stamina
        self.main_shape = None
        self.striker = None
        self.hands = 1
        self.damage_type = 'b'
        self.base_ap = 0
        self.hand = True
        self.added_mass = self.weapon.added_mass
        self.length = 0 #Used to add or subtract from base weapon length got added/reduced reach
        self.side_restrict = True #Determines if the attack can only hit one side of the enemy (i.e. hook from R hand only hitting left side)
        self.restricted_locs = [] #Locations that can never be targeted with this attack (i.e. foot with uppercut)
        self.allowed_angles_r = [] #Angles that are allowed as an index of angles (0 = N-> S, 7 = NW -> SE, 8 = thrust) (i.e. N->S with an uppercut)
        self.allowed_angles_l = [] #Angles that are allowed as an index of angles (0 = N-> S, 7 = NW -> SE, 8 = thrust) (i.e. N->S with an uppercut)
        self.main_area = 0
        self.mech_adv = 0
        self.force_scalar = 1 #Used to adjust force/damage for the attack

        for k in kwargs:
            for key in self.__dict__:
                if k == key:
                    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

        #self.set_dynamic_attributes()

    def set_dynamic_attributes(self):

        for t in self.damage_type:
            if t == 'b':
                if self.striker == 'main':
                    shape = self.weapon.main_shape
                else:
                    shape = 'round'
                if shape == 'wedge':
                    self.main_area = self.weapon.main_length * self.weapon.avg_main_width
                    self.mech_adv =  self.weapon.main_depth / self.weapon.main_width
                elif shape == 'round':
                    #Using Hertz's result, but using fixed f value built off of added_mass + fist mass (.86) and v of 40 f/s2 and fixed p_ratio for target
                    #Equation: https://www.quora.com/Is-the-area-of-contact-between-a-cylinder-and-a-flat-surface-infinitely-small-Is-it-a-point
                    if self.striker == 'main':
                        material = self.weapon.main_material
                        width = self.weapon.main_width
                        length = self.weapon.main_length
                    elif self.striker == 'shaft':
                        material == self.weapon.shaft_material
                        width = 1
                        length = self.weapon.shaft_length
                    else:
                        material = self.weapon.accent_material
                        width = length = 1
                    e_calc = ((1-(material.p_ratio * material.p_ratio))/(material.elasticity*10))+((1-(.4*.4))/5)
                    self.main_area = sqrt((4*((.86 + self.added_mass)*40)*width)/(3.514*(e_calc)*min(length, 8)))
                elif self.main_shape == 'flat':
                    self.main_area = min(self.weapon.main_length,8) * min(self.weapon.main_width,8)

            elif t == 's':
                if self.main_shape == 'blade':
                    self.main_area = min(self.weapon.main_length, 8) * self.weapon.avg_main_width
                    self.mech_adv =  self.weapon.main_depth / self.weapon.main_width
                elif self.main_shape == 'de blade':
                    self.main_area = min(self.weapon.main_length, 8) * self.weapon.avg_main_width
                    self.mech_adv =  (self.weapon.main_depth/2) / self.weapon.main_width

            elif t == 'p':
                if self.striker == 'main':
                    shape = self.weapon.main_shape
                    length = self.weapon.main_length
                    depth = self.weapon.main_depth
                    width = self.weapon.main_width
                else:
                    shape = 'point'
                    if self.striker == 'shaft':
                        length = min(self.weapon.shaft_length, 8)
                        depth = width = 1
                    else:
                        length = depth = width = 1
                if shape in ['point', 'blade']:
                    wedge1 = length / width
                    wedge2 = width / depth
                    #Double each (since there are two wedges per side) and multiply for full MA of tip
                    self.mech_adv = (wedge1*2)*(wedge2*2)
                    self.main_area = depth * length * width

            else:
                if self.main_shape == 'hook':
                    wedge1 = self.weapon.main_length / self.weapon.main_width
                    wedge2 = self.weapon.main_width / self.weapon.main_depth
                    #Double each (since there are two wedges per side) and multiply for full MA of tip
                    self.mech_adv = (wedge1*2)*(wedge2*2)
                    self.main_area = self.weapon.main_depth * self.weapon.main_width



        if self.damage_type in ['s','b']:
            self.stamina += self.weapon.weight + int(self.weapon.weight*self.weapon.axis_vs_com)
            self.base_ap += min(self.weapon.weight/10, (self.weapon.weight * 10)/self.weapon.axis_vs_com)
            self.added_mass = self.weapon.weight / self.weapon.com_perc
            self.attack_mod += (20 - ((self.weapon.weight*10) * self.weapon.com_perc))
            self.parry_mod -= ((self.weapon.weight*10) * self.weapon.com_perc)

            if self.weapon.main_num > 1:
                self.attack_mod += self.weapon.main_num * 5
                self.parry_mod -= self.weapon.main_num * 20
        else:
            self.stamina += self.weapon.weight/2
            self.base_ap += self.weapon.weight * 5
            self.added_mass = self.weapon.weight/10

            if self.damage_type == 'p':
                self.attack_mod -= self.weapon.weight/10
                self.parry_mod -= self.weapon.weight * 5
            else:
                self.attack_mod += -5 + (self.weapon.main_num * 5)
                self.parry_mod -= self.weapon.main_num * 20
```

More code by request. Here is the code for the weapon class (which the attack references) and the materials class (which weapon references):

```py
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = ''
        self.shafted = False #Used to determine if wpn has a shaft
        self.allowed_main_materials = [] # List of materials applicable for the main surface. Young's modulus prevents copper and bronze swords longer than 24", for example
        self.main_material = m_steel #Damage component (blade, head, etc) material
        self.shaft_material = m_wood
        self.grip_material = m_leather
        self.accent_material = m_steel
        self.attack_mod = 0
        self.parry_mod = 0 #Mod to weilder's ability to parry with weapon
        self.b_striker = 'accent' #Striking surface for damage type. Can be main, shaft, accent, or none
        self.s_striker = 'main'
        self.p_striker = 'main'
        self.t_striker = 'none'
        self.hands = [1] #List can include 0,1,2
        self.quality = 'Average'
        self.base_name = 'Weapon'
        self.bname_variants = [] #A list of variant names for the weapon
        self.skill = None #This is the default skill used for the weapon. String
        self.length = 1
        self.shaft_length = 0 #Also used as tethers for flail and whip like weapons
        self.shaft_diameter = 0
        self.shaft_num = 0
        self.pre_load = False #Used to account for weapons that can be preloaded with velocity, like flails or staves
        self.avg_main_width = 1 #1.25 average longsword
        self.main_width = 1 #Absolute width at widest point
        self.avg_main_depth = .1 #.14 is average for a sword blade
        self.main_depth = .2 #Absolute depth at deepest point
        self.main_shape = 'de blade' #Acceptable values: de blade, blade, point, wedge, round, flat, hook
        self.main_num = 1 #Number of main attack surfaces, mostly used for flails/flogs
        self.accent_cuin = 1 #Cubic inches of accent material, such as the crossguard and pommel on a sword
        self.main_com = .5 #Center of mass for the main weapon component
        self.main_loc = .1 #Location along the total length for the main weapon component
        self.accent_loc = .05 #Location along the total length for the accent component
        self.grip_loc = .03 #location along the total length for the grip
        self.main_weight = 0
        self.shaft_weight = 0
        self.accent_weight = 0
        self.grip_weight = 0
        self.weight = 0
        self.main_length = 0
        self.added_mass = 0

        self.damage_type = 'b'
        self.stamina = 0




        #Maximums; used to procedurally gen weapons
        self.main_len_range = (0,0) #Tuple containing min and max range for acceptable lengths
        self.main_depth_range = (0,0)
        self.main_avg_depth_range = (0,0)
        self.main_width_range = (0,0)
        self.main_avg_width_range = (0,0)
        self.length_range = (0,0)
        self.shaft_length_range = (0,0) 
        self.shaft_diameter_range = (0,0)
        self.max_main_num = 1
        self.max_shaft_num = 1


        self.main_only_com = 0
        self.shaft_only_com = 0
        self.accent_only_com = 0
        self.com = 0 #Center of mass for the whole weapon
        self.com_perc = 0 #com as a percentage
        self.axis_vs_com = 0 #Shows COM relative to grip location (axis for swings). Used to determine AP/stamina costs.

        self.main_hits = 0
        self.staff_hits = 0
        self.accent_hits = 0        

        self.min_pwr_1h = 0 #1 pwr = 1 ft/lb; accelleration = 40 f/s2; weight of average hand = .86 lb
        self.min_pwr_2h = 0 #1 pwr = 1.5 ft/lb; accelleration = 40 f/s2; weight of average hand = .86 lb

        self.solidness = 1 #Used in damage calc
        self.sharpness = 1 
        self.pointedness = 1

        self.base_attacks = []
        self.attacks = []
        self.base_maneuvers = []
        self.maneuvers = []
        self.guards = []

        self.cost = 0
        self.normality = 1

        for k in kwargs:
            for key in self.__dict__:
                if k == key:
                    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

        self.set_dynamic_attributes()

    def set_dynamic_attributes(self):
        #Determine which variant name to use
        if len(self.bname_variants) > 1:
            n_idx = roll_dice(1, len(self.bname_variants))
            n_idx -= 1

            self.base_name = self.bname_variants[n_idx]

        #Name weapon using quality and material, if applicable
        if self.main_material is not m_tissue:
            if self.quality != 'Average':
                self.name = self.quality + ' ' + self.main_material.name + ' ' + self.base_name
            else:
                self.name = self.main_material.name + ' ' + self.base_name
        else:
            self.name = self.base_name

        self.attack_mod = 20 * quality_dict.get(self.quality)
        self.parry_mod = 20 * quality_dict.get(self.quality)

        self.main_weight = ((self.main_length * self.avg_main_depth * self.avg_main_width)*self.main_num) * (self.main_material.density * .03)
        self.shaft_weight = (self.shaft_length * self.shaft_diameter * (self.shaft_material.density * .03)) * self.shaft_num
        self.accent_weight = self.accent_cuin * (self.accent_material.density * .03)
        self.grip_weight = self.grip_material.density * (.3 * max(self.hands))
        self.weight = self.main_weight + self.shaft_weight + self.accent_weight
        self.main_only_com = ((self.main_length*self.main_com)+(self.main_loc*self.length))*self.main_weight
        self.shaft_only_com = (self.shaft_length*.5)*self.shaft_weight
        self.accent_only_com = (self.accent_loc*self.length)*self.accent_weight
        self.com = (self.main_only_com + self.shaft_only_com + self.accent_only_com)/self.weight #Center of mass for the whole weapon
        self.com_perc = self.com / self.length #com as a percentage
        self.axis_vs_com = self.com_perc - self.grip_loc #Shows COM relative to grip location (axis for swings). Used to determine AP/stamina costs.

        self.main_hits = (self.main_material.elasticity * 1450000) * (self.main_weight/(self.main_material.density*.03)) * self.main_material.toughness


        self.min_pwr_1h = ((self.added_mass + .86) * 40)/1 #1 pwr = 1 ft/lb/s; accelleration = 40 f/s2; weight of average hand = .86 lb
        self.min_pwr_2h = ((self.added_mass + 1.72) * 40)/1.5 #1 pwr = 1.5 ft/lb/s; accelleration = 40 f/s2; weight of average hand = .86 lb

        if self.main_material.elasticity < 1: self.solidness = self.main_material.elasticity
        if self.main_material.hardness < 1: 
            self.sharpness = self.main_material.hardness
            self.pointedness = self.main_material.hardness
        else:
            self.sharpness = sqrt(self.main_material.hardness)
            self.pointedness = self.main_material.hardness

        #Damage calc = ((((added_mass + fist mass) * velocity) / main_area) * mech_adv) * sharpness or hardness or pointedness

        main_materials_cost = self.main_material.cost * self.main_weight
        shaft_materials_cost = self.shaft_material.cost * self.shaft_weight
        grip_materials_cost = self.grip_material.cost * self.grip_weight
        accent_materials_cost = self.accent_material.cost * self.accent_weight

        #Crafting costs. 1 day skilled labor = ~5 material cost
        main_crafting_cost = self.main_material.craft_diff * self.main_weight
        shaft_crafting_cost = self.shaft_material.craft_diff * self.shaft_weight
        grip_crafting_cost = self.grip_material.craft_diff * self.grip_weight
        accent_crafting_cost = self.accent_material.craft_diff * self.accent_weight


        self.cost = main_crafting_cost + main_materials_cost + shaft_crafting_cost + shaft_materials_cost + grip_crafting_cost + grip_materials_cost + accent_crafting_cost + accent_materials_cost

        self.normality = self.main_material.normality * self.shaft_material.normality * self.grip_material.normality * self.accent_material.normality


class Material():
    _allMaterials = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #Below is to create a list of instances of this class
        self._allMaterials.append(self)

        self.name = None
        #Goal: Hardness and elasticity set the hits for the material, toughness then scales them up or down. 
        self.hardness = 1 #Scalar. 1 = ~7 Brinell, roughly very hard wood. Copper 85, Bronze 180, Iron 300, Steel 400-600
        self.elasticity = 1 #Scalar. Basically resistance to deformation. 1 = Wood, average modulus of elasticity ~10 GPa. Bone 18, Gold 79, Copper 100, Bronze 120, Iron 210, Steel 200
        self.toughness = 1 #Scalar. Resistance to breaking when deformed. 1 = Wood, very non-brittle. 10 = Gold, very malliable. .5 = Steel, somewhat brittle. 0.1 = stone
        self.p_ratio = .5 #Poisson's ratio. Non-scaled, use actual values
        self.normality = 1 #Scalar. How rare the material is. 1 = Iron, very common. Gold is 4 million times rarer than Iron, but probably it will be ~.01 in game
        self.cost = 1 #Scalar. Raw cost of the material (taking into account refining costs). 1 = Wood, cheap $0.23/lb. 10 = Copper, $2.50/lb. 82,000 = Pure Gold
        self.craft_diff = 1 #Scalar. Difficulty of crafting. 1 = 1 day of crafting per lb of finished material. Cost of 1 day of a craftsman = 5 
        # For metals, hardness modifies it. Hardened Steel takes 5 days to craft 1 pound of weaponry. 
        self.density = 1 #Scalar. Relative density per cubic inch. 1 = Wood, .03 lb/in3. Copper = .32, Silver = .38, Gold = .7, Iron = .28, Bronze = .3, Steel = .28
        for key in self.__dict__:
            for k in kwargs:
                if k == key:
                    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.set_dynamic_attr()

    def set_dynamic_attr(self):                   
        if self.craft_diff == 0:
            self.craft_diff = .078 * self.hardness
            self.craft_diff = round(self.craft_diff, 2)
```

Comment: Just because two objects are instances of the same class, does not mean it will take the same, constant time to perform a deep copy of either of them. `deepcopy` is recursive and visits every node in the object tree, constructing a totally independent copy, so the amount of time it takes really just depends on how many things / references are in that tree. My hunch is that you're somehow taking your `atk` copy and in some way or another binding to one of your attack objects. It's hard to say though. Could you post more code? Honestly anything could be relevant. What do you do with `atk`?

Comment: The for-loop in your `__init__` can probably be written as just `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`

Comment: Did you try reducing your code until the problem goes away? The last thing you delete before that happens is probably the cause ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The comment about recursions (and reading the docs on deepcopy) gave me a hunch that perhaps the deepcopy is duplicating ALL objects in the attack instance, including the weapon object, the materials objects inside the weapon object, etc. Doing some debugging seems to indicate that this is what's happening (the address for the weapon object is different for every iteration). So I'm working on debugging that right now, though I'm not totally sure how to do it other than overriding the __deepcopy__ method.

Comment: As for what I'm doing with it, the attack instance contains the default settings for the attack. I'm then deepcopying it and modifying it to add to the list of attacks for the character. I'm now beginning to wonder if this is the most boneheaded way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it; The issue was as user10987432 suspected, it was creating copies of all objects up the tree. I fixed it by removing the weapon reference in the constructor and passing each individual attribute as a kwarg (ugh). Makes for a very ugly 4-line call, but it works and is fast. I'll see if I can shorten it once it gets on my nerves enough; for now I can just copy/paste and only change relevant fields.

Edit: I fixed the problem much more cleanly by making the individual attacks all child classes of the Attack class and just creating instances of them for each actor. Not sure why I didn't do that originally, I'm doing it for maneuvers already, but it's much easier to read and debug now. Thanks again to everyone for the help.